# Constructor Definition with Inheritance

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

My professor gave the following code to show an example of inheritance:

```
//Base class
class Inventory {
    int quant, reorder; // #on-hand & reorder qty
    double price; // price of item
    char * descrip; // description of item
public:
    Inventory(int q, int r, double p, char *); // constructor
    ~Inventory(); // destructor
    void print();
    int get_quant() { return quant; }
    int get_reorder() { return reorder; }
    double get_price() { return price; }
};
Inventory::Inventory(int q, int r, double p, char * d) : quant (q), reorder (r), price (p)
{
    descrip = new char[strlen(d)+1]; // need the +1 for string terminator
    strcpy(descrip, d);
} // Initialization list



//Derived Auto Class
class Auto : public Inventory {
    char *dealer;
public:
    Auto(int q, int r, double p, char * d, char *dea); // constructor
    ~Auto(); // destructor
    void print();
    char * get_dealer() { return dealer; }
};
Auto::Auto(int q, int r, double p, char * d, char * dea) : Inventory(q, r, p, d) // base constructor
{
    dealer = new char(strlen(dea)+1); // need +1 for string terminator
    strcpy(dealer, dea);
}
```

I was confused line "Auto::Auto(int q, int r, double p, char * d, char * dea) : Inventory(q, r, p, d)", what is the definition "Inventory(q, r, p, d)" doing. Similarly
in the line "Inventory::Inventory(int q, int r, double p, char * d) : quant (q), reorder (r), price (p)" I'm not sure what he is doing with quant (q), reorder (r), price (p). Are these the same variables that were defined in class as int quant, reorder and double price? If so, why did he have to use in the constructor. And why/how did he use a constructor from a base class to help define "Auto" class constructor.

Comment: I see that this is not your code but I think it's worth mentioning that this code is pretty ugly, I think it would be a really really good idea to not call a class `Auto` given the presence of the `auto` keyword in the language. Also using the char * seems to be a non-idiomatic way to do this in c++, using std::string is just such a better way of going about things in almost all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is using "initialization lists".

He is calling the base class constructor. `Auto::Auto(int q, int r, double p, char * d, char * dea) : Inventory(q, r, p, d)` defines a constructor for the `Auto` class which calls the parametrized constructor of the `Inventory`. The parameterized constructor needs to be called because `Auto` is inheriting from `Inventory` and `Inventory` defines a parameterized constructor. C++ specifies that if you define a parameterized constructor, the default constructor is overridden and the only way you can instantiate an object of that class or any sub-class is by calling the parametrized constructor (or by defining an alternate default constructor).

In the case of `Inventory::Inventory(int q, int r, double p, char * d) : quant (q), reorder (r), price (p)`, he is initializing the fields `quant`, `reorder` and `price` with the values `q`, `r` and `p` respectively. This is actually a shorthand and you can instead assign the values in the constructor body (unless the member is a constant).

Comment: Why does he need to call "Inventory(q, r, p, d)". What does the line do? And I don't see anything in the constructor of Auto which require a parametrized constructor of Inventory. Is it for "just in case"

Comment: In the main he never defines a variable of "Inventory", thus never instantiating it. However, he calls "Auto car(3, 1, 8745.99, "Four-Door", "GM"). Does this automatically call the Inventory constructor because of the constructor definition in Auto, thereby initializing the values of "quant", "reorder", "price" and "d".

Comment: You can only instantiate an object of type `Auto` if the constructor of `Auto` somehow calls the parameterized constructor of `Inventory` because it _inherits_ from it. So according to the principles of OOP, an `Auto` object _is_ an `Inventory` object.

Comment: So since he instantiated Auto, he didn't need to instantiate Inventory. But how about setting the private member values of "quant", "reorder", "price" and "d" which are used as the constructor for Inventory. How are they called?

Comment: When you call `Inventory`'s parameterized constructor like this: `Inventory(q, r, p, d)`, it does that for you. `Inventory`'s constructor does that.

Comment: However, in the main of my Professor's code he doesn't call Inventory anywhere. He only executes "Auto car(3, 1, 8745.99, "Four-Door", "GM");"

Comment: That statement calls `Inventory(q, r, p, d)` as specified in the 'initialization list' of `Auto`'s parameterized constructor.

Comment: So the power of "parametrized constructor" lies only when it is used with inheritance. Because as you said in the case of Inventory, my professor could have just gone into the constructor and assigned the value of quant, reorder and price

Comment: That would be a bad conclusion actually. You could instead say initialization lists are mostly used to call the base class constructor. Parameterized constructors on the other hand have no relation with inheritance.

Comment: So I don't see why should I declare the values of quant, reorder and price as a parameter, why not just declare in the constructor?

Comment: 'the values of quant, reorder and price' are taken from the user and is hence taken as arguments for the paramerized constructor. They are not constant.

Comment: But how is it any different from going into the constructor and writing quant = q, reorder = r and price = p, since my constructor is already carrying parameters Inventory(q, r, p, d)

Answer (score 4):

In the children constructor, you always call the constructor of the father by default. If that constructor receives arguments, you have to explicitly write the call by using the : notation.